# Retrieving objects from fetchedResultsController.sections?[section]

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, sections

I am populating the sections of a UITableView sections with the following:

```
fetchedResultsController =
  NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                             managedObjectContext: managedContext,
                             sectionNameKeyPath: #keyPath(Players.team),
                             cacheName: nil)
```

My UITableView has the `team` in the section.  I would also like to add the city to the section.  I don't think I can add two items to the section.  I can see that the following has the data required.  But how do I retrieve the city information?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    let sectionInfo = fetchedResultsController.sections?[section]

    print("sectionInfo \(String(describing: sectionInfo?.objects))")

    return sectionInfo?.name
}
```

results:

```
sectionInfo Optional([<Time_on_Ice.Players: 0x1c028cf30> (entity: Players; id: 0xd000000000100000 <x-coredata://EE1C8D6B-3FC5-4460-9F7F-3830328B6688/Players/p4> ; data: {
    birthdate = "1990-02-07 05:00:00 +0000";
    city = "Tampa Bay";
    division = Atlantic;
    firstName = Steven;
    headshot = <ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 01000048 00480000 ffe10058 45786966 00004d4d 002a0000 00080002 01120003 00000001 0001>;
    height = "5'11\"";
    lastName = Stamkos;
    league = NHL;
    level = Professional;
    number = 91;
    playersShiftRelationship = "<relationship fault: 0x1c403d060 'playersShiftRelationship'>";
    position = Centre;
    shoots = Right;
    team = Lightning;
    weight = "177 lb";
})])
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have a team entity and each player contains all the team information independently. This kind of denormalisation is not necessarily wrong in core-data.  So if every entity with the same team has the same city, you can just access the first element in section and get it's `city` property.  It will be the same for every element in the section